# npm run build won't create build directory

Tags: reactjs, webpack

It's my first time running a build to deploy a react website. When I run npm run build, nothing happens. I tried running npm run build:all and I do get a build directory created but with no index.html file.

My current package.json is:

```
"eslint": "eslint \"src/**/*.js\"",
"start": "concurrently \"npm run dev:server\" \"npm run dev:bundle\"",
"test": "jest",
"dev:server": "cross-env NODE_PATH=./src nodemon --exec \"babel-node src/server/server.js\" --ignore .reactful.json --ignore public/",
"dev:bundle": "webpack -wd",
"verify-tests": "jest --coverage",
"build:react": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress -p",
"build:node": "babel src -d build --config-file ./babel-node.config.js --copy-files",
"build:all": "npm install && npm run build:react && npm run build:node",
"prod:start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production NODE_PATH=./build pm2 start -i max build/server/server.js --update-env --name react-testProd",
"prod:stop": "pm2 stop react-testProd",
"prod:reload": "pm2 reload --update-env react-testProd",
"prod:logs": "pm2 logs --update-env react-testProd",
"build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
```

My current webpack config is:

```
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve('./src'), path.resolve('./node_modules')],
  },
  entry: {
    main: ['./src/renderers/dom.js'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('public', 'bundles'),
    filename: isDev ? '[name].js' : '[name].[chunkhash].js',
  },
```

Any idea what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

I cant see anything particularly wrong but you can try using CopyWebpackPlugin

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: './index/html', to: 'relative/path/to/dest/' }
    ])
  ]
}
```

Comment: Tried it, but getting: Invalid options object. Copy Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.

Comment: Thats usually due to using an incorrect version - depending on the version of webpack you are running you will need to install the corresponding version of CopyPlugin